# Application start page blank, but server running

Tags: grails, localhost

So, I'm new to grails development and this is my problem.

When I've created a grails-application and when I'm browsing to localhost I get this:

Browser  (localhost : 8080 /test3)

Page (Cannot GET /test3)

and it doesn't matter what I do. Have anyone encountered this problem?

This is the server saying it's up and running.

```
Created file test/unit/test3/HelloControllerTests.groovy
n156-p125:test3 bobby_falck$ grails run-app test3
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/test3
```

The thing is it didn't give me this error-message a couple of days ago. :S

Comment: Can you provide your Grails version? It occurs if you create a fresh new app?

Comment: What does your UrlMappings.groovy look like?

Comment: I just had to change the port -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think that this helped me to solve the problem:

grails> -Dserver.port="someportnumber" run-app

:)

Comment: Well, I don't remember. Sorry.